# Distance Matrix Map Helper not working for Rails 5 w/Geocoder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps, geocode

I am simply trying to plot a map for the distance_matrix Google API that shows the current location of one object and the distance between the other. (Simple GPS) using lon and lat -- Currently, both objects are configured correctly to support the Distance Matrix Map, but I cannot get the map to show in the view. I don't know if I am coding the parameters correctly. How can I setup my Distance Matrix helper method to show the map in the view with the current_location and time that it takes to reach the destination?

trucks_helper.rb

distance_matrix_map [Doesn't work]

```
 def distance_matrix_map_for(location, options={})
    params = {
        :origins => [location.lat, location.lon].join(", "),
        :zoom => 15,
        :size => "500x500",
        :destinations => [location.delivery.delivery_order.order.lat, location.delivery.delivery_order.order.lon].join(","),
        :sensor => true
    }.merge(options)
    query_string = params.map{|k, v| "#{k}=#{v}"}.join("&")
    image_tag "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&#{query_string}", :alt => location.current_location_title, class: 'img-fluid img-rounded'
  end
```

static_map_for builder [Works]

```
def static_map_for(location, options = {})
    params = {
        :center => [location.lat, location.lon].join(","),
        :zoom => 15,
        :size => "300x300",
        :markers => [location.lat, location.lon].join(","),
        :sensor => true
    }.merge(options)

    query_string = params.map {|k, v| "#{k}=#{v}"}.join("&")
    image_tag "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?#{query_string}", :alt => location.current_location_title, class: 'img-fluid img-rounded'
  end
```

Comment: The Distance Matrix API doesn't return a map nor an image; it returns plain text JSON. It also does not take a "zoom" or "size" parameter. Please review the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro#DistanceMatrixResponses). You will either need to parse the JSON to get the "text" and "value" from the "duration" field and place that value in a Static Map, or you can simply use the [Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide#directions_mode)

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thank you.